# Integrating CKEditor with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, ckeditor

I'm trying to integrate a [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_Java_released) with a JSP page ([Demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo)). I have downloaded jar files from [here](http://ckeditor.com/download) in *the CKEditor for Java* section and added the `ckeditor-java-core-3.5.3.jar` file to the project library. I'm following [this](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Integration) installation guide but that downloaded zip folder contains no client-side scripts.

It is mentioned there "*Attention: client side scripts are not included in this package.*" beside the Download zip button of *the CKEditor for Java* section on the [download page](http://ckeditor.com/download). So, where are they available, nowhere? Are there other CKEditors (or FCKEditors) available for JSP to integrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you're installing the Java version of CKEditor, so your editor will be configured through tags like `<%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>` rather than with scripts.

If you want to use the full script editor, download the first zip [here](http://ckeditor.com/download) (Named just `CKEditor`) and follow the instructions [here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Installation).

I've recently used it in a project I'm working on and had no problems with it, even through the use of jQuery.

Comment: The first zip means [this](http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%203.6.4/ckeditor_3.6.4.zip) one?

Comment: @Tiny Indeed. I should have stated the name of the file. My bad :).

Comment: I shall try it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The CKEditor has been displayed successfully as you mentioned. Just one query however, if you know. It displays the image browse but doesn't display the **Browse Server** button as can be seen in [this](http://ckeditor.com/demo) demo to browse images (click the image button located on the editor). It just displays a *text field* instead (without a browse button beside the *text field*). Do you know how to display it, please?

Comment: In that case you'll have to include a file browser CKEditor can interact with, like [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com) which is an ajax file browser that will allow you to either retrieve or send images from and to the server.

Comment: I have tried with [this](http://download.cksource.com/CKFinder/CKFinder%20for%20PHP/2.2.2.1/ckfinder_php_2.2.2.1.zip) CKFinder  and it indeed worked and displayed the *Browse Server* button but when that button is clicked, it issues an error like `It was not possible to properly load the XML response from the web server.
XML Parsing Error: unclosed token Location: http://localhost:8084/wagafashion/ckfinder/ckfinder.html...` because it attempts to go into the `ckfinder.php` file through `index.html` (it contains no JSP files at all). Is it not possible to use it in JSP? Do you know another way?

Comment: Try [CKFinder for Java](http://download.cksource.com/CKFinder/CKFinder%20for%20Java/2.2.2/), the version you got is for PHP.

Comment: That zip file contains a WAR. It's very confusing. According to [this](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/CKEditor_Integration) integration guide, it seems to me that it requires a JAR. Also seen [these](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/Java/CKEditor_Integration#CKFinder.setupCKEditor) instructions but they seem to be fake (I'm using Tomcat). You should have already configured and integrate CKFinder with CKEditor. How did you do that? Could you please let me know?

Comment: [This](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Integration#Replacing_Selected_Textarea_Element) approach for CKEditor also worked. Sorry for too much concerned. I was about to post this a separate question but it may be considered to be a silly question on this site.

Comment: @Tiny Glad to see you got it working. There are no silly questions actually, the only silly thing about a question is to ask something that is unclear, is way too broad or is highly dependable on an oppinion rathre than a concrete solution. Not your case, tough, since you had a good background on the topic and you were proactively searching for a solution. Keep it up.

Comment: @Tiny - are you using JSP ? i have downloaded the Java it got one .war file I read in the docs they tell us to deploy it will please explain about how you have made it working with the Java version Ckeditor ?

Comment: @webgeek : I used CKEditor and CKFinder at that time about three years ago but three years later, right now, I find it hard to remember what exactly I did at that time to make both of them to work in a JSP application as I am currently active mainly with JSF nor I have that JSP project in my hands. Otherwise, I could have posted a separate answer basically covering how to integrate a CKEditor along with a CKFinder in JSP.

Comment: Oh Ok, Thanks for your response.